# Android app just to open website

Tags: android, html

I'm using HTML5 and Phonegap to create very simple Android App, which is suppose to open website - URL, e.g.: www.website.com
I used iframe for this and it works, but when I scroll website content is flashing/blinks of some sort, like content isn't loading or rendering on time.

How to make this work without "blinking" ?

```
<iframe src="http://novalja-pag.net/" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%" allowfullscreen seamless></iframe>
```

Thanks

Comment: Upload the code so people can see what is causing the problem

Comment: <iframe src="www.link" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%" allowfullscreen seamless></iframe>